# Looping through XML Elements in Python, finding duplicates, and summing

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I'm using XML for the first time (not by choice, but by requirement for an output file).  I need to turn this:

```
<StaffRecords>
    <EmployeeName>John Doe</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeTitle>Financial Analyst</EmployeeTitle>
    <Positions>
        <JobRecord>
            <Class>100</Class>
            <Location>7</Location>
            <Salary>40000</Salary>
        </JobRecord>
        <JobRecord>
            <Class>100</Class>
            <Location>7</Location>
            <Salary>40000</Salary>
        </JobRecord>
    </Positions>
</StaffRecords>
```

... into this:

```
<StaffRecords>
    <EmployeeName>John Doe</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeTitle>Financial Analyst</EmployeeTitle>
    <Positions>
        <JobRecord>
            <Class>100</Class>
            <Location>7</Location>
            <Salary>80000</Salary>
        </JobRecord>
    </Positions>
</StaffRecords>
```

So it needs to take the record, match the JobRecord's Class and Location, sum the salary, and then delete one of the JobRecord entries.

I've attempted to use .finds and .findalls with some Python loops, comparing values, etc., but I haven't had any luck whatsoever.

Is there a way to do this without converting it to a Python list of dicts (or a pandas DataFrame), making the needed adjustments, and then trying to convert it *back* to XML?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is easy to implement via XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see below (no external library is used)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import SubElement
from collections import defaultdict


xml = '''<StaffRecords>
    <EmployeeName>John Doe</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeTitle>Financial Analyst</EmployeeTitle>
    <Positions>
        <JobRecord>
            <Class>100</Class>
            <Location>7</Location>
            <Salary>40000</Salary>
        </JobRecord>
        <JobRecord>
            <Class>100</Class>
            <Location>7</Location>
            <Salary>40000</Salary>
        </JobRecord>
        <JobRecord>
            <Class>100</Class>
            <Location>17</Location>
            <Salary>300</Salary>
        </JobRecord>
        <JobRecord>
            <Class>100</Class>
            <Location>17</Location>
            <Salary>200</Salary>
        </JobRecord>
    </Positions>
</StaffRecords>'''

data = defaultdict(int)

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
pos = root.find('.//Positions')
for rec in root.findall('.//JobRecord'):
    data[(rec.find('Class').text,rec.find('Location').text)] += int(rec.find('Salary').text)
    pos.remove(rec)
for k,v in data.items():
    rec = SubElement(pos, 'JobRecord')
    clazz = SubElement(rec,'Class')
    clazz.text = k[0]
    loc = SubElement(rec, 'Location')
    loc.text = k[1]
    sal = SubElement(rec, 'Salary')
    sal.text = str(v)

ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaffRecords>
   <EmployeeName>John Doe</EmployeeName>
   <EmployeeTitle>Financial Analyst</EmployeeTitle>
   <Positions>
      <JobRecord>
         <Class>100</Class>
         <Location>7</Location>
         <Salary>80000</Salary>
      </JobRecord>
      <JobRecord>
         <Class>100</Class>
         <Location>17</Location>
         <Salary>500</Salary>
      </JobRecord>
   </Positions>
</StaffRecords>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lxml` and Xpath to find and replace elements

```
from lxml import etree
from _functools import reduce

tree = etree.parse('/home/lmc/tmp/test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
# find salaries and assign sum to last one
steps = tree.xpath('//EmployeeName[.="John Doe"]/following-sibling::Positions/descendant::Salary')
total = reduce(lambda x, y: int(x.text) + int(y.text),steps)
steps[1].text = str(total)
# get Position and JobRecord elements
pos = root.xpath('//EmployeeName[.="John Doe"]/following-sibling::Positions')
recds = root.xpath('//EmployeeName[.="John Doe"]/following-sibling::Positions/JobRecord')
# clean Positions element and insert the one with the sum
pos[0].clear()
pos[0].insert(0,recds[1])
#print(steps, recds)
# write to disk so MAKE A BACKUP!
etree.ElementTree(root).write('/home/lmc/tmp/test.xml', pretty_print=True)
```

Result:

```
<StaffRecords>
    <EmployeeName>John Doe</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeTitle>Financial Analyst</EmployeeTitle>
    <Positions><JobRecord>
            <Class>100</Class>
            <Location>7</Location>
            <Salary>80000</Salary>
        </JobRecord>
    </Positions>
</StaffRecords>
```